# is it possible to make this python turtle image code shorter?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

[image: image to make]

This is my code so far, is there a way to make the code smaller so you don't have to type in every move, and how to move the whole image, because I don't have enough space for the remaining part of the image. I already tried changing the values of `screen.setworldcoordinates` but then I didn't see the image anymore.

```py
from turtle import *
screen = Screen()
screen.clear()
screen.screensize(200, 200)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-250, -250, 350, 250)

alex = Turtle()
alex.shape("turtle")
alex.speed(10)

alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(60)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(60)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(60)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(60)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(30)
alex.right(90)
alex.forward(60)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're always moving in steps of 30, the only variation is on the turns (Left, right, or none). So, you can drive the turtle using a string of turning instructions to be executed before each step forward:

```
from turtle import *

alex = Turtle()
alex.shape("turtle")
alex.speed(10)
alex.up()
alex.setx(-window_width()//2) # start on left side of window
alex.down()


turns = "-LRR-LLRLLRR-LLRRLRR-LLRRLRR-LLR-LRR-LLRLLRR-LLRLLRR-LLRRLRR-LLR"
for turn in turns:
    if turn=="L":alex.left(90)
    if turn=="R":alex.right(90)
    alex.forward(30)
```

This specific pattern could also be obtained recursively (like a fractal):

```
def pattern(turns,n,step=30,angle=90):
    if not n: return alex.forward(step)
    for turn in turns:
        if turn=="L":alex.left(angle)
        if turn=="R":alex.right(angle)
        pattern(turns,n-1,step,angle)

pattern("-LRR-LLR",2)
```

*You can play with the pattern function using deeper recursion or different turn sequences or angles to get interesting drawings:*

```
pattern("-LRR-LLR",3,10)
pattern("-LRRL-",4,3)
pattern("-LRRL",4,8)
pattern("-LRR-RRR-",3,15)
pattern("-LRR-LLR-",3,20,angle=120)
pattern("-RRRLLLLLLRRR-",2,10,angle=45)
pattern("-LR-R-R-RR",3,20)
pattern("-LRRRLLLLRRRL",3,3,75)
pattern("-LRRRLLLLRRRL",4,2,75)
```

Comment: thank you a lot! but what does the dashes between the L and R do and means ?

Comment: Since the dashes are neither L nor R, they represent "No turning".  These will let the turtle go one more step in the current direction.  This corresponds to your `alex.forward(60)` calls which become "Don't turn" + "forward(30)"

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the turtle moves in a file and let your program read and parse the file and execute the moves.

The file format, could be:

```
left 90
forward 30
```

or:

```
l90
f30
```

Or you can invent a json format and practice json as well.

Comment: why not show an example? and I think you meant _use_ instead of _invent_

Comment: I showed two examples of how the file format could be? Yes, use json, but invent his own json format. I'll not give any python code examples in this case, that will not help him/her in the long run.

Comment: perhaps, perhaps it won't help them (maybe if you explain in detail? don't know), that seems kinda debatable but to be fair they have shown their attempt? partially; so... otherwise the answer doesn't have thatttt much value, it might as well have been a comment to just use files but as I said the given case is kinda debatable

Comment: I agree to that, it should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a simpler, less compact approach.  If we examine the curve, we find that it's made up of repetitions of a simpler curve:

[image]

The only thing that varies is the turtle's orientation when it starts drawing this shape.  So if we can encapsulate the code that draws this shape, we can simplify, and shorten, our program significantly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def wave():
    alex.forward(30)
    alex.left(90)
    alex.forward(30)
    alex.right(90)
    alex.forward(30)
    alex.right(90)

    alex.forward(60)

    alex.left(90)
    alex.forward(30)
    alex.left(90)
    alex.forward(30)
    alex.right(90)
    alex.forward(30)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)

alex = Turtle()
alex.shape('turtle')
alex.speed('fastest')

alex.penup()
alex.setx(-250)
alex.pendown()

for angle in (0, 90, -90, -90, 0, 90, 90, -90):
    alex.left(angle)
    wave()

screen.exitonclick()
```

I'm not saying this is the best approach, but rather that a first step to reducing the size of any program is to look for patterns in your code and data to see if you can work in larger conceptual chunks.

> how to move the whole image, because I don't have enough space for the
> remaining part of the image

You don't need `setworldcoordinates()`, the problem is you called `screensize()` (does something else) when you really want `setup()`.  Then you can use `setx()` to move the turtle to the left side of the window:

[image]